# Android application private publish on Google play

Tags: android, google-play

We have an application that has to be tested for "Rating feature" i.e user will click a button and will be redirected to the application's play store page to rate the application.

Is it possible to publish an application on Play Store but keep it private or provide access to only a few people. It should remain invisible for rest.
After testing we may remove the application and then upload again at a later time.

If its not possible how can we test the rating feature.

Comment: You can't have a private application on Google Play, but what is there much to test for the rating? If you really need to test, you may use the market link to another app already published.

Comment: Yes , I am aware of the approach, but many wont agree. I will try "The Beta Family "

Comment: "The Beta Family " sounds like a great testing environment, though I don't see how that will help you test the rating on GooglePlay :)

Comment: @Adinia: If the application is already available on the store then the feature will work regardless of the medium of distribution. But if the app does not exist at all, then it is a problem. That is however, true even if Google Play was to have such an option of _private testing_. That is a dilemma the OP will have to address. If the _rating feature_ is the only function the OP needs to test, he will _have to_ make the app live.

Comment: Right now yes, its only the rating feature , I meant I will try out the The beta family for a more generic testing purpose.

Comment: @IceMAN It's only that the title and text of the question didn't really match...your answer is perfect for the title(+1), but useless for the content :D If Google Play would offer _private testing_, the app should have a link, and I suppose the rating feature (i.e opening the market to that apps's page) could be also tested.

Comment: @Adinia: I agree it is _useless_ ;-) but under the circumstances, there really isn't a choice for the OP. As I said before, it is a dilemma that the OP alone can address. I have given my suggestion (based on available options) that deals with one-part of the question.

Answer (score 10):

The Google Play Store now supports both alpha and beta testing.

Once you've created your app in the console, under the APK section, you can choose to upload alpha and beta versions that are not publicly available.

You control who can access the test versions using google+ communities - make these private so you control who can join them.

You have to publish your app to the store, before you can get the link to share with your testers for them to opt in to the testing program, but don't worry, provided you have no production apk uploaded, your app won't appear in the play store for users who aren't in the testing program.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play store does not have a feature / facility where you can upload an APK for private testing. You will have to rely on a third-party service for doing so.

[The Beta Family](http://thebetafamily.com/) is one such web service that allows you to do just that.

If you want to distribute the application to a specific list of people, they also offer a feature called [Supersend](http://thebetafamily.com/supersend/)

Their service is free. You can read their [FAQ's](http://thebetafamily.com/faq) to help you know more about it.

<strike>There is another well known web service called [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/android/). See which one works for you. I had good results with *The Beta Family* though and never ventured to try *TestFlight*.</strike> (As pointed out by **LocalPCGuy** in the comments, *TestFlight* does not support Android testing anymore).

And as already answered by **Stew J** on this same thread, The Google Play Store supports BETA and ALPHA testing.

Comment: TestFlight has since been purchased by Apple and is no longer supporting Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use [licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) to do this.  Licensing is available for free apps too.  You can [assign](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#test-response) a status like `LICENSED` or `NOT_LICENSE` using gmail addresses.