# How to publish an app privately on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish an app privately, that means app should not showing when user search on Google Play Store.

I want to share app link to user and then user will be download the app on Google Play Store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android application private publish on Google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059406/android-application-private-publish-on-google-play)

Comment: @codecrazer There are any option to share link and download app.

Comment: Not really. Another way is through Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) software. The idea is that if the link leaks, only authorized users can get your app. You could always host the APK yourself and have the user side-load.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Authorized users means that was authorized by EMM or Google

Comment: Authorized as in login from a list ether on EMM software or your private alpha in Play Store.

Answer (score 9):

There are three options.

- The first option is to integrate with the [EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/private-apps), sometimes called "Managed Play". This is designed for companies to publish private apps to their users.
- If you use Managed Play you can also publish [Self-hosted private apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145182).
- Another option is to use a [closed testing track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213). This is sometimes called Alpha or Beta testing, and that is what it is designed for - not for publishing private apps. An app which is only published on a closed track is not visible in search on the Play store. And testing users can't rate or review it. However since it is designed for testing users have to opt-in. You probably don't want this option, as it isn't designed for publishing private apps.

The first option is probably best, but it depends on the reason you want to do a private app.

Answer (score -6):

Publish it as **BETA** release, it won't be shown on Google play.

Comment: The beta release which is now known as an open beta will be visible on google play store.